# Не отображаются кнопки из файла в JS на wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить следующую проблему: у меня в файле JS указаны изображения кнопок для слайдера (вперед, назад). Но при подключении к WordPress кнопки пропадают. Я предполагаю, что перед их директорией нужно указать что-то подобное: php bloginfo('template_directory'). Как это работает? Что нужно указать? Заранее большое спасибо за ваш ответ. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во первых код нужно вставлять кодом, а не картинкой. Во вторых ты не написал  как подключаешь js. Исправляй вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Надо указывать абсолютный путь от корня сайта.

`<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/prev.png'; ?>"`

либо просто

`<img src="/wp-content/themes/my-theme/img/prev.png">`

где `my-theme` - название папки вашей темы.